# How to change Hive Server Timezone

Tags: apache-hive

I am using [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) on RedHat. Hive version is `1.2.1`. The current Timezone in Hive is `EST` and I want to convert it to `GMT`. 
PS: I want to change the Hive Server Timezone and I am not asking about using a particular function in Hive that can convert `EST` timezone to `GMT` timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive picks timezone of your JVM, so try changing JVM timezone. Setting "TZ" environment variable should help.

Comment: I'll check this in my production environment and let you know the updates.